# How to get a specific number in a phone number using javascript

Tags: javascript, substring

I would like to get the following number after the first "7" in a phone number.
Let's say "077777777" its "7" and "0788787878" its "8" and "0727923743" is "2" etc how can i do this in javascript
i was thinking of something like this

```js
var phone = 0784848236.substring(0784848236.indexOf("7"));
```

but its far different.

Comment: Well, that's not going to work because you're not wrapping your string in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```js
var match = '0784848236'.match(/7(.)/);
match = match && match[1];
console.log(match);
```

NB: This will result in `null` when there is no match.

Note that it is important to have your phone number in string format. If you use a number data type, and have it converted to string on the fly, you'll loose prepadded zeroes. See how looking for a zero fails in this case:

```js
var phone = 0784848236;
var match = String(phone).match(/0(.)/);
match = match && match[1];
console.log(match); // null !!! The zero is lost.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is close, but has two issues:

1. `0784848236` is an int, not a string, so you cannot call `substring()` or `indexOf()` on it. You should instead use `"0784848236"` (in quotes).
2. `substring()` gives you the entire string after the specified index, but you only want the first character of that substring. So you don't actually need to use `substring()` here at all. Instead, you can just use [direct access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) (index into).

Instead, try something like this:

`var phone = "0784848236"["0784848236".indexOf("7") + 1];`

Comment: You can also use `String(0784848236)` to convert `0784848236` to `"0784848236"`, as the other answer suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the substring method, you need to pass in a string.

You also need to provide a start and end index. Here is the reference for the method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring
str.substring(indexStart[, indexEnd])

If I was to change your question by declaring a string from the phone number then I could use substring on the string. Like this:

```
var pn = '0784848236';
var n = pn.substring(pn.indexOf("7") + 1, pn.indexOf("7") + 2);
```

Now the result will be the next number following the '7'

Answer (score 0):

> to get the following number after the first "7" in a phone number

Here are two approaches:

[***String.prototype.substr()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [***String.prototype.indexOf()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) functions approach:

```js
var phone = 0784848236, i,
    strPhone = String(phone),  // string representation of phone number
    nextDigit = ((i = strPhone.indexOf("7")) !== -1)? strPhone.substr(i + 1, 1) : null;
    
console.log(nextDigit);
```

---

[***String.prototype.split()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [***Array.prototype.indexOf()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) functions approach:

```js
var phone = 0784848236,
    arr = (''+0784848236).split(''), i,
    nextDigit = ((i = arr.indexOf("7")) !== -1)? arr[i+1] : null;

console.log(nextDigit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's working for me:

```
var num="0784848236";
var numberSeven = num.indexOf("7");

var yourNumber = num.substring((numberSeven + 1), (numberSeven + 2));
```